# View/configure access log of Keycloak HTTP server

Tags: keycloak

How to view/configure access logs of HTTP server Keycloak uses?

I'm trying to investigate *connection_refused_error* to Keycloak admin UI.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding the following `<access-log/>` tag to your server configuration file, for example: `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                ...
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <!-- Add the following one line -->
                    <access-log prefix="access." />
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <filter-ref name="proxy-peer"/>
                </host>
            </server>
```

You can see `access.log` in your `standalone/log/` directory after restarting your Keycloak server and the log file is rotated daily with a name like `access.2019-07-26.log`.

**EDIT:**

You can also use JBoss CLI as follows:

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=access-log:add
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

these commands adds the one line to `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<access-log/>
```

the next command shows the access log settings (default values):

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=access-log:read-resource
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {
        "directory" => expression "${jboss.server.log.dir}",
        "extended" => false,
        "pattern" => "common",
        "predicate" => undefined,
        "prefix" => "access_log.",
        "relative-to" => undefined,
        "rotate" => true,
        "suffix" => "log",
        "use-server-log" => false,
        "worker" => "default"
    },
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}
}
```

You can change an attribute (for example, `prefix`) by the command:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting=access-log:write-attribute(name=prefix,value=access.)
```

Comment: It would be very nice to be able to add the access logs line using jboss-cli, i guess its better than changing the standalone xml and have to keep it updated.

Comment: @rodrigocoelho Added the way to use jboss-cli. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However its not working with my latest Keycloak (standalone-HA).
If i do a $cd /subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/setting and  then i list, i only get: http-invoker, so, no access-log. Doing this because i don't want to change the standalone-ha xml.

Comment: Since the access-log was not yet created as a setting i had to create before adding attributes. It works now! Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

To extend Kohei TAMURA answer:

In order configure the access log without reloading Keycloak:

1. Add line `<access-log worker="default"
   directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access." suffix="log"/>`
   to *standalone/configuration/standalone.xml* or 
   *standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml* if clustered configuration is used.
2. Reload Wildfly server configuration without restarting it:

   ```
   jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect
   [standalone@localhost:9990 /] reload
   ```